# Are there disadvantages to an adapted Canon EF-S zoom vs Sony SEL 18-200 lens for my Sony Nex?

Tags: lens, canon, equipment-recommendation, lens-adapter, sony-nex

I want to buy a universal zoom lens 18-200 (maybe 18-135) for my Sony Nex. At Sony I found only Sony SEL 18200 lens that is expensive.

There are adapters Canon EF-S to Sony E-mount (with providing autofocus etc.) Canon EF-S 18-200 with the adapter cheaper than Sony SEL 18200. Canon EF-S 18-135 is even cheaper.

But I doubt that the Canon lens with Sony Nex body will work as it should.

Is there a problem with that?

Comment: If you only want to use one lens you're probably better off with a superzoom camera than a changeable lens camera.

Comment: Relevant posts: http://www.lensrentals.com/blog/2013/09/there-is-no-free-lunch-episode-763-lens-adapters and http://www.lensrentals.com/blog/2014/06/the-glass-in-the-path-sensor-stacks-and-adapted-lenses

Comment: @MichaelClark sometime yes, but.... I have a DSLR that I use with a superzoom when hiking, and with three nice primes when I feel more on the way to be creative... ;-).

Answer (score 4):

An adapter is great if you already have Canon lenses or want to share lenses between Canon DSLRs and NEX cameras - but it isn't that good compared to getting the Sony lens.

No adapter is perfect (actually, the lens and camera aren't perfect either)

The adapter will add some more (usually small and almost unnoticeable, unless you pixelpeep) misalignment to your camera and lens existing (hopefully small and unnoticeable) misalignment - it will always make the optical quality a little bit worse.

Also, it might but doesn't have to (don't know about the specific model you plan buying) make auto-focus slower and/or less accurate.

Add to it that the Canon EF-S 18-135 (that I have and love) and the EF 18-200 are both "kit quality" lenses and are, how to say it gently, not optically the best lenses Canon makes.

Also the Canon 18-135 and 18-200 are big and heavy compared to NEX lenses.

So, you are taking a lens that isn't that great to begin with - and that's too big and heavy to be used comfortably with your camera - and add to it an adapter that will make it worse and even slightly bigger and heavier.

Answer (score 2):

Sony 18-200mm for $748 at [BH](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/863264-REG/Sony_SEL_18200LE_18_200mm_f_3_5_6_3_OSS_Lens.html)
Canon ef-s 18-200 for $699 [BH](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/582444-USA/Canon_2752B002_EF_S_18_200mm_f_3_5_5_6_IS.html) + Metabones adapter for $399 for Af [BH](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/983747-REG/metabones_mb_ef_e_bm3_canon_ef_to_e_mount_nex.html)

The sony is both cheaper and lighter. If you dont have any canon cameras or don't plan to get canon cameras, I would stick with Sony if I was you. Metabones reviews say AF is slow with it. I'm not sure how it compares vs AF with a sony camera but it's something to consider as well.

Make sure you read tons of reviews for either combination before you purchase to make an informed decision. Don't go by just one opinion.

There's also a Tamron 18-200 for $739